# Angularjs locationProvider routing not working

Tags: angularjs

I've setup routing and enabled html5 mode for the locationProvider:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    // removing this locationProvider will make route work
    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
      enabled: true,
      requireBase: false
    });

    $routeProvider      
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : '../assets/js/app/views/user/form.html',
            controller  : 'UserFormController'
        })
        // yada yada yada

});
```

Now when I got to the base url:

```
http://localhost/projectapp/index.php/foo
```

The controller is not loaded and neither is the form.html, possibly because the route isn't loading the controller. When I remove the $locationProvider html mode from the config the controller is loaded. Why isn't the controller loading?

Comment: because it is now overriden by angular routing config. Angular has its own routing management separate from your php framework

Comment: @MidTwo I'm not sure what you mean, codeigniter's routing doesn't effect this scenario

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for [HTML5 Mode errors](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$location/nobase),

> If you configure $location to use **`html5Mode`** (history.pushState), you need to specify the base URL for the application with a **`<base href="">`** tag or configure $locationProvider to not require a base tag by passing a definition object with **`requireBase:false`** to **`$locationProvider.html5Mode()`**

Have you added the `base` tag in your HTML?

Comment: Looks like you've got an infinite loop running. Have you manually called a `$digest` or `$apply` somewhere? Or anything else that might be causing an infinite loop? Maybe creating an array of scope elements and incrementing the length of the array?

Comment: No and since the app works fine without locationProvider this confuses me

Comment: Hmm weird. Could you share more code? With what you have shared so far, I don't see anything that might be causing an infinite loop or digest cycle

Comment: Hmm I tried removing most the code to narrow down problem, still getting error I'll post more code tonight :(

Comment: Error seems like, it wasn't caused by this html5Mode. !!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
  enabled: true,
  requireBase: false
});
```

But to work with html5 mode. You need to add following tag in index.html file.

```
<html>
<head>
<base href="#" />
</head>
</html>
```

I hope this will work :)

Comment: When I do that the url changes to from /#/ to /#%2F

Comment: Yes. If you don't want to put '#' in your url then you can change it to <base href="/" />. This base href is used to make it compatible for search engine locator.

Comment: Yep I originally I had <base href="/" /> which lead me here to ask why my controller wasn't loading

Comment: Then make requirebase: true